# Preventing a specific move in moveRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, tableview

I have a UITableView in my Objective-C iOS app, of which I need to have a specific cell displaying information while **all** the others cells should move freely.

With my current code, I prevented said cell to be moved by other cells, but it is still possible to move underneath it.

This cell is not part of my Data model so I really need to keep this in the controller layer.

In other words, I'm looking for a way to prevent the **default behaviour**.

Below is my current code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
        
    if (destinationIndexPath.row == [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0]-2) {
        //prevent the move
    }
    else {
        [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] moveItemAtIndex:sourceIndexPath.row toIndex:destinationIndexPath.row];
    }
}
```

What should I change in order to obtain the desired functionality?

Comment: Implement the `UITableViewDelegate` method `tableView:targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:toProposedIndexPath:`

Answer (score 1):

Use targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath as below,

```
// Allows customization of the target row for a particular row as it is being moved/reordered
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toProposedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)proposedDestinationIndexPath {


    if( proposedDestinationIndexPath is ok ) {

        return proposedDestinationIndexPath;

    } else {

        return sourceIndexPath;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to implement this delegate method?

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Comment: Please read the question again. The OP already states that this method is used to prevent a certain cell from being moved. The question is how to prevent other rows from being moved below it.